# Load external image source using variable

Tags: image, angular

I couldn't load an external image using an url variable.
The problem is that Angular auto complete the url to add `localhost:3000/` at the beguining of the url.

Here is my component:

```js
import { Component, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Cite } from './cite';
import { Engin } from './engin';
import { Station } from './station';
import { EnginService } from './engin.service';

@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: 'my-engin-detail',
    template: `
    {{imgUrl}}
    <img [src]= "imgUrl" width="42" height="42" />
    `,
     styles: [`
     `]
 })
 export class EnginDetailComponent implements OnInit {
     constructor(private enginService: EnginService) {

     }
     @Input()
     engin: Engin;
     imgUrl: string;
     ngOnInit(): void {
         this.enginService.getImgUrl(this.engin.id_engin)
             .then(url => this.imgUrl = url);
     }
 }
```

the output is

> 192.168.0.102/resultsdetails/image/assets/E207_1.png //that's => {{imgUrl}}
>
> ERROR 404 :
> http://localhost:3000/192.168.0.102/resultsdetails/image/assets/E207_1.png
> 404 (Not Found)

Here angular2 compiler autocomplete the url with "http://localhost:3000/" and i don't want that.

However this works fine:

```html
<img src="192.168.0.102/resultsdetails/image/assets/E207_1.png" width="42" height="42/>
```

So, I don't know how to inject a variable in the [src] without an autocompletion with `/localhost:3000`

Comment: var imgUrl = "192.168.0.102/resultsdetails/image/assets/".  Then use it as the url

Comment: the content of imgUrl  is correct, I already test it with {{imgUrl  }}

Comment: it should be //192.168.0.102/... or http(s)://192.168.0.102/... Your url is relative, so browser adds domain o the beginnig of it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In case of "relative" url you have, it could be done like this:

```
<img [src]= "'//' + imgUrl" width="42" height="42" />
```

Comment: If I understand the question correctly, the problem is that angular makes the URL relative even when it shouldn't be.